# Can't edit the size of the mesh in object mode

Tags: modeling

Why in the lower left i can't edit any mesh ? I can't press anything. (Blender 2.78). I've tried to disable some addons but nothing, appears to be blocked.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Can you capture the full screen? Perhaps you've got the 3D view in a mode that's blocking editing.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/mBTManu.jpg new example with a simple sapling, I can't edit anything of the tree and if i switch on the edit mode ( obviously ) the settings are gone and i can't modify the tree. Sorry for my bad english I hope you understand what i said.

Comment: I see the fields are gray, have you tried editing the numbers anyway? You might also want to try File > Load Factory Defaults.

Comment: I can do very complicated mesh but i can't solve these problem on my own...  Thanks Ron!

Comment: Most likely you unchecked *Global Undo*  option in User Prefs > *Editing*. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/886/bottom-of-tool-shelf-grayed-out.

Comment: No, i tried to disable one specific addon "extra curves" and the problem was solved.