# Can't seen primitive options when adding a new mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, interface

When I add a new mesh, I don't see any primitive options. Ie. being able to adjust the number of vertices etc.

If I create a brand new file then the option to adjust the core mesh primitives is visible in Properties panel. So it appears to be linked to the file I'm working on.

Driving me nuts.

Comment: Welcome to the site! The properties for added objects are not linked to anything. Probably you have Global Undo disabled or some addon which prevented this to work as expected, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/886/bottom-of-tool-shelf-grayed-out

Comment: Thanks @MrZak I managed to figure it out and posted my solution below.

Answer (score 6):

I had somehow hidden the *Operator* panel.

Open the Tool Shelf *View > Tool Shelf* then click the tiny plus icon just above the *View Select Add* menu. It should be at the very bottom of the Tool Shelf Panel.

[image]

For Blender version 2.91.0 click on *View* at the top right, and check the box named *Adjust last Operation*

[image]