# Disabled settings on mesh creation

Tags: objects, interface

I have an odd question that (while it doesn't stop progress) is fairly annoying. Here's what I do. Shift + A -> Mesh -> UV Sphere. Pretty straight forward right? Well, once the sphere is created the options are disabled. The only couple of addons that I've installed have been Ice Tools and Retopoflow. I also downloaded 2.78b (I was in 2.78) and I'm having the same issues. I assume it may be in the saved preferences?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's likely caused by the User Prefs, enable the Global Undo.

Comment: Thank you and that worked. Do you happen to know why that happens?

Comment: It's described pretty well in the linked answer - http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2155/1245. In short Blender has to have access to redo history as it undoes one action and redoes it with new parameters when changing options in the Last Operator Panel.